Calculate totals in BigQuery
I have the following table:



Time
Sales




1/1/2020
30


2/2/2020
50


1/1/2021
100


2/2/2021
200



I need to subtract the most actual year against the previous one like:



Time
Sales Difference




1/1/2021
100-30 =  70 here


2/2/2021
200-50 = 150 here




How can I get that?
Is it possible in calculated fields?


I've left you an answer that I think will help. In return, please make an effort to improve the quality of your question (so that it will help future people searching StackOverflow). Try to be much more specific about what you're asking. For example, the title should be something like 'Calculate year on year change of a metric in BigQuery'. In general you will get better answers if you put lots of effort into writing detailed questions, and you will also help others with the same problem in future.

Try this on for size:
WITH
eg_table AS (
    SELECT DATE('2020-01-01') AS month, 30 AS sales,
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2020-02-02') AS month, 50 AS sales,
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-01-01') AS month, 100 AS sales,
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE('2021-02-02') AS month, 200 AS sales,
)

SELECT
    month,
    sales,
    FORMAT_DATE('%b', month) AS month_name,
    sales - LAG(sales) OVER(year_on_year_window) AS year_on_year_change,
FROM
    eg_table
WINDOW year_on_year_window AS (
    PARTITION BY FORMAT_DATE('%b', month) ORDER BY month
)
ORDER BY
    month

First I've set up your example data as a CTE called eg_table. I've renamed 'time' to 'month' (best practice is not to use built-in names like 'time', which is a data type, as field names).
Reading your question, I think you want to do a year-on-year comparison. Therefore we must use a window function (also known as an analytic function).

the LAG function (which returns the previous value) must be used with a window clause (OVER)
we define a window that partitions by (similar to group by) the name of the month and orders the data for that month name (so that Jan 2020 comes before Jan 2021 comes before Jan 2022, etc)
so LAG(sales) OVER(year_on_year_window) will return the sales value for the previous recorded value of sales (for that month name)
finally, then, sales - LAG(sales) OVER(year_on_year_window) gives the difference between the current value of sales and the previous recorded value (for that month name)

Output looks like this:
Row month       sales   month_name  year_on_year_change
1   2020-01-01  30      Jan         null
2   2020-02-02  50      Feb         null
3   2021-01-01  100     Jan         70
4   2021-02-02  200     Feb         150

... as was required.
